# will Prepare Statment discard cause write to fail in Cassandra?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax

We have 2 m3.medium cassandra systems. And we are seeing this type of warning

> 2016-11-27 00:53:06,097 QueryProcessor.java:123 - 1 prepared statements discarded in the last minute because cache limit reached (10 MB) WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2016-11-27 00:57:06,097 QueryProcessor.java:123 - 1 prepared statements discarded in the last minute because cache limit reached (10 MB)

Would we loose any incoming write data when this happens ?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing bad will happen with this. The drivers will handle it if you try to use a statement thats been evicted, recreating it.

The warning is a good note though. Particularly, its flag that you may be creating or recreating prepared statements constantly. In that case you are probably running slower than if you just don't prepare them at all. Your query will be blocked by waiting for an acknowledgement of the statement being prepared on the coordinator, which can be something like 2-3x the latency.

Answer (score 0):

**No, Cassandra will not loose any incoming write.**
Cassandra cached all the prepared statement.In your case prepared statement  Cache limit exceeded.It will evict some prepared statement and prepared the new statement